# Пунктуация в конструкции с цитированием диалога

Tags: пунктуация, диалог, цитирование

О цитировании состоявшегося прежде между двумя особами диалога.

*Нет, я спрашиваю, что это такое: "— Чай или кофе?, — Пожалуй, чай".*

Первые шесть слов относятся к настоящему времени (говорящего интересует состоявшееся в прошлом), остальное — цитата вопроса и ответа, данного некоторое время назад.

Интересует пунктуация в подобных конструкциях с цитированием.

Answer (score 1):

Диалоговая речь может быть записана двумя способами.

С абзаца (§ 51.1):
— Чай или кофе?
— Пожалуй, чай.

В строку (§ 51.2):
«Чай или кофе?» — «Пожалуй, чай».

Если повторяются слова, принадлежащие другому лицу (то есть чужой текст), то получается цитирование, и эти слова выделяются кавычками (§ 51.5).

Можно написать так (с перечислением реплик после собственно вопроса):
— Нет, я спрашиваю, что это такое? «Чай или кофе?» «Пожалуй, чай».

Или так (с вопросительным перечислением реплик):
— Нет, я спрашиваю, что это такое: «Чай или кофе?» «Пожалуй, чай»?

Или даже так (как полную цитату; знак вопроса после кавычек):
— Нет, я спрашиваю, что это такое «"Чай или кофе?" — "Пожалуй, чай"»?

[Знаки препинания при диалоге](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html)

Comment: Почему в третьем случае не стоит двоеточие?

Comment: Если в третьем случае поставить двоеточие, то будет похоже на конструкцию при прямой речи. А это не так. Как пример: _Что это такое "быть самим собой"?_ P. S. Чуть не забыла: Ваш "диалогический вопрос" интересен. Надеюсь, с правкой Вы согласны?

Comment: Да, безусловно. Имелось в виду "пунктуация (чего?) конструкции", но без предлога "в" пунктуация, вероятно, могла бы означать некоторый процесс, действие, совершаемое над конструкцией. Чтобы не возникло такого неверного понимания, был добавлен предлог.